# C++ Transferring objects from memory to a file

Tags: c++, file, object, persistence

Sometimes it is needed to store a collection of linked objects in a file for future use. In this regard, there are two most obvious approaches, neither of which seems quite satisfactory. The first approach is to create a mapping of pointers to file offsets, like this:

```
struct A
{
   int data;
   std::list<B*> links;
};

struct B
{
   char data;
   std::list<C*> links;
};

typedef unsigned Offset;
std::map<void*,Offset> ptr2ofs;
```

The problem with this approach is that it requires additional mapping, which may be hashed for faster access, but overall will introduce time and space overhead per each saved link.

The second approach is to include the offset field directly in the data structures:

```
struct A
{
   int data;
   Offset offset;
   std::list<B*> links;
};
```

This makes writing operations much faster, but the offset fields become redundant after saving, and will produce memory overhead after loading. So, in this case two sets of structures will be needed, one for saving data, and another one for loading it:

```
struct A_write
{
   int data;
   Offset offset;
   std::list<B*> links;
};

struct A_read
{
   int data;
   std::list<B*> links;
};
```

Thus, both of the approaches obviously have significant drawbacks and neither can be considered as the reference approach. But is there a way to improve them?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not using a DB? (e.g. SQLite)

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi good point...Alhough offset_pointers(suggested by Jason S) are a way to go ahead, I would prefer more generalized scheme as storing it in database.

Comment: This does not solve anything. If you initially create the structures as C++ classes, you will need another set of structures for loading and accessing the data through the DB interface. This is the same as the second approach, when you need two sets of structures.

Answer (score 0):

Ever heard of [offset pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html)? They store the relative address rather than the absolute address, so if you just want to plunk down a block of memory into a file and read it back into memory another day, all the address references will still be valid.

If you want to use a serialization library, I'd look at one of the following. Yeah, you could design it yourself, but someone's already been through this trouble before....

- Google [Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/google/protobuf/)
- [Cap'n Proto](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/)
- [Google FlatBuffers](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers)

Comment: This only works if the size of the block is known in advance. If you fill the link lists on the fly then all pointers will be stabilized just before writing to the file. What you are suggesting is mapping dynamic memory structures 'as is' into the output file. This would bring much bigger overhead than one additional unused field per object.